# Webmatrix Web Pages - Login using Parse (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, web, parse-platform, webmatrix-3

I have an issue i cant figure out, i have a small web matrix webpages site, i am using Parse.com SDK and when a user logins in - i am logging them in on the server side.

The problem is that if another user anywhere else opens the site, they are logged in with the user that logged in elsewhere.

e.g. I am in the UK and i login - i get logged in fine and land on the dashbaord page. now any other person anywhere else in the world goes to the site xxx.com they are automatically redirected to the dashbaord as the user i last logged in with.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Parse SDK is for client side (not for Server side). I suggest you to see the source code of Parse in [github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET).
If I want to explain you in detail: reason is that the DLL has shared Token in `ParceUser.cs` file that filled automatically by your login and it's shared over whole DLL and is singltone pattern.